# Find an element that repeated $\frac{n}{5}$ times in sorted array

Tags: algorithms, searching

> We are given a sorted array$A[1..n]$, we are searching to find an
> element that repeated $\frac{n}{5}$ times in array.How we can do it in
> $logn$?

I find an solution in $O(n)$,with checking each element $i$,and calculate it appearance in interval $A[i+\frac{n}{5}]-A[i]+1$. If $A[i]=A[i+\frac{n}{5}]$ then we find it.

But how we can decrease it to $logn$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the interval you're looking for is so big that it must hit one of five evenly-spaced indexes between 0 and $n$ (say $n/6,2n/6,3n/6,4n/6,5n/6$), so we have five candidate values for the repeated element. Use two binary searches for each candidate value to find its start and end indexes.

Comment: Can you explain more about your solution?i can't understand your argument about five evenly-spaced indexes.

Comment: Edited to be more specific. Note that the target interval can't "fit between" these indexes.

Comment: excuse me, Can you explain your algorithm on a simple example?because when i partition the array to $6$ part with size $\frac{n}{6}$ i can't run your algorithm on it to find solution!.

Comment: Suppose the array : $A[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]$ such that 1's appear $\frac{n}{5}$ times with size $30$, now if we partition the array with each size $\frac{n}{6}$,but the first partition include 0 and 1s.

Comment: We aren't partitioning the array, we're identifying 5 possible answers. In your example, we find A[n/6]=1, so we binary search to find the smallest and largest i such that A[i]=1 and subtract these two indexes to get the number of 1s. If it's greater than n/5, we're done. Otherwise, our next candidate value is A[2n/6].